# Inettuts inside javascript doesnt work when i move the div

Tags: javascript, asp.net, widget

I created a widget framework using inettuts and added some database functionality with ajax in asp.net and sqlserver. Widgets are loaded according to the database data of the user but i got a problem.When i move a widget the javascript inside it doesnt work. here are my codes what do you think the problem is.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery(".c").hide();
jQuery("#widgetbodycontainer").click(function(e) {
    console.log("clicked");
    // if user clicks on a .c element or a descendant of one
    if (jQuery(e.target).hasClass("h") || jQuery(e.target).parents(".h").length) {
        jQuery(e.target).next(".c").slideToggle(200);
    }
});​
});

</script>
<div id="container">

<div id="widgetbodycontainer" >

<div class="layer1">

<p class="h">Company </p>
<div class="c">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></div>
<p class="h">Person</p>
<div class="c">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></div>
<p class="h">Result</p>
<div class="c"></div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably because your ajax behaviour is replacing elements, destroying any event handlers which are directly tied to them. You will need to use [event delegation](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/), which, in essence, means tying a "smart" handler to a suitable parent container. Try:

```
// as of jQuery 1.7
jQuery("#widgetbodycontainer").on("click", ".h", function () {
    jQuery(this).next(".c").slideToggle(200);
});
```

- http://api.jquery.com/on/

EDIT: Since you are using a prehistoric release of jQuery, you'll have to do event delegation the old-school way:

```
jQuery("#widgetbodycontainer").click(function(e) {
    console.log("clicked");
    // if user clicks on a .c element or a descendant of one
    if (jQuery(e.target).hasClass("h") || jQuery(e.target).parents(".h").length) {
        jQuery(e.target).next(".c").slideToggle(200);
    }
});​
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/5ajfa/)

Comment: @tfeseas - there was a missing comma, which I have since fixed.

Comment: now nothing works the divs are collaped and mouse click doesnt respond.

Comment: do you think it could be because of positioning?

Comment: @tfeseas - which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: @tfeseas - heh, well, do you think you can upgrade to at least v1.4? That explains why it does not work. Ideally, upgrade to the latest.

Comment: i tried but then the widget framework doesn't work properly.i will try 1.4 now

Comment: is there any other option to use collapsible divs that would work even i change the place of the widget.

Comment: @tfeseas - yes, there is. I would suggest attempting the upgrade. Failing that I'll edit the answer with something that will work in your case.

Comment: widget framework doesnt work properly when i upgrade it.Given that i took that collapse thing from internet i can change it if there is a sample but widget framework is too complex to change now since i got 24 hours left to finish it

Comment: Okay. Please give me about 20 minutes and I'll write you something which will work.

Comment: @tfeseas - and there was a bug in my latest edit, but I've fixed it and included a demo. Hope that sorts things out for you.

Comment: well i still couldn't make it work.The new code is in the question area,what do you think the problem is?